# How to find out if a Node has children

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

I'm doing some `HTML` scraping.

I transform the `HTML` page to valid `XML` using [`HTMLCleaner`](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) and extracting data from a `<table>`

I need to check if a given `<td>` has child nodes or not, because the flow of the program will be different in each case. Is there any `hasChildren` equivalent? I have not found anything like it on the documentation. The `<td>` looks like this:

```
<td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
</td>
```

What's the easiest way to find out if it has any child nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import scala.xml._
def isEmpty(node: Node) = node.child. // All children
  // Filter out empty text nodes
  filter {childNode => !childNode.isInstanceOf[Text] || !childNode.text.trim.isEmpty}.
  isEmpty
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._

scala> def isEmpty(node: Node) = node.child. // All children
     |       // Filter out empty text nodes
     |       filter {childNode => !childNode.isInstanceOf[Text] || !childNode.text.trim.isEmpty}.
     |       isEmpty
isEmpty: (node: scala.xml.Node)Boolean

scala> val emptyTd = <td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
     | </td>
emptyTd: scala.xml.Elem = 
<td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
</td>

scala> val nonEmptyTd1 = <td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
     | Lorem ipsum
     | </td>
nonEmptyTd1: scala.xml.Elem = 
<td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
Lorem ipsum
</td>

scala> val nonEmptyTd2 = <td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
     | <br />
     | </td>
nonEmptyTd2: scala.xml.Elem = 
<td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;">
<br/>
</td>

scala> isEmpty(emptyTd)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isEmpty(nonEmptyTd1)
res1: Boolean = false

scala> isEmpty(nonEmptyTd2)
res2: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `org.htmlcleaner.TagNode` has method `public boolean hasChildren()`. In your case it will return if 'td' has children:

```
import org.htmlcleaner._
val cleaner:HtmlCleaner  = new HtmlCleaner()
val html = """
             |<html>
             |
             |<head />
             |
             |<body>
             |      <table>
             |          <tbody>
             |              <tr>
             |                  <td style="width: 1%; padding-right: 5px;"></td>
             |              </tr>
             |          </tbody>
             |      </table>
             |  </body>
             |</html>
           """.stripMargin

    val td = cleaner.clean(html).findElementByName("td", true)
    td.hasChildren  //returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

What I tried to do before without success was this:

```
node isEmpty
```

the `node` being my `<td>` in this case.

Now what I did was actually try to fetch first level of the data I expect, and see if it is empty

```
node \\ "span" isEmpty
```

And that gave me the result I wanted. Don't know if it is the best way to do this, but I'm leaving the answer here as a suggestion in case nobody answers.